# Aim lower from high elevation?

Tags: kinematics, projectile

I've heard you must aim lower relative to the target (possibly below it??) when shooting from an elevated position versus shooting from the same level as the target. How can this be?

Comment: This is not true. You do have to aim lower than you would if you were shooting at an elevated target, but aiming below a target will never work.

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with using a scope, or any adjustable sight -once you've adjusted your sights on level ground, they will be off slightly for shots that aren't horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a rifle that is sighted in for a particular distance when shooting on a horizontal trajectory, you do have to aim a bit low when shooting down at a target that is the same distance away.  In addition, you have to aim a bit low when shooting up at a target that is at that same distance.  The reason: the acceleration due to gravity has the maximum effect on the bullet when it is traveling horizontally.  If you shoot that same bullet straight up, the bullet will take a bit longer to get to the target because gravity is decelerating it, but the bullet trajectory will be absolutely straight as it travels to the target.  Likewise, if you are shooting straight down at the target, the bullet will get to the target in a slightly shorter time because it is being accelerated by gravity, but the bullet trajectory will be absolutely straight as it travels to that target.  This means that the rifle that is sighted for a horizontal trajectory will have a scope (or open sights) that point the rifle barrel a bit above the target, and the parabolic trajectory of the bullet will cause it to arrive at the target.  Since a shot that is straight up or straight down will not have a parabolic trajectory, the scope (or open sights) will result in a shot that arrives above the target if the rifle is pointed directly at the target.  This effect will also be seen to a lesser degree for any angle that is not horizontal, requiring that you aim progressively lower than the target as the line of sight deviates more and more from horizontal.

Comment: Absolutely straight trajectory? In gravitational field? Or you are taking about shooting in space?

Comment: I'm talking about shooting on the surface of the earth.

Comment: How can you have a perfectly straight trajectory in presence of gravity? Maybe only if you shoot straight up and neglect Coriolis effect.

Comment: Shooting straight up or straight down, as indicated in my post.  And note - I have already worked this problem out in excruciating detail, using Solved in an Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score -1):

My initial thoughts were that shooting uphill or downhill would result in the projectile hitting below the target or no significant deviation.  The general consensus on the internet at shooting related sites claim that one must aim below the target shooting both uphill and downhill.
Turning to the equations of projectile motion my calculations initially supported my conclusion.
X = Vxot = (VoCosθ)t
Y = Vyot-1/2gt^2=(VoSinθ)t-1/2gt^2
When sighting down the bore the projectile always has a greater deviation below the point of aim when shooting at a positive or negative angle relative to the horizontal.  This results due to the reduction in the horizontal component of velocity (Vox=VoCosθ) with the change in angle θ.  The reduction in Vox increases time (t) which results in greater acceleration downward (-1/2gt^2).
However, this didn’t take into account the fact that firearms are typically “zeroed in” at some range.  This results in a difference between the sighting angle and the bore angle. 
Taking this into account produced some effects which I hadn’t anticipated.
The angle α between the sighting angle and bore angle changes the results.
When shooting uphill the angle between the bore and horizontal is increased by α.  When shooting downhill the angle between the bore and horizontal is reduced by α.
This results in lower values of Vox when shooting uphill vs. shooting downhill relative to the sighting angle.  The net effect is that taking into account this differential between the sighting angle and bore angle shooting uphill will result in the bullet striking lower than the target and shooting downhill the bullet striking higher than the target when the horizontal shot is zeroed on the target.

With all this said the effect is minimal at normal angles of shot and zeroing ranges.  The effect only become significant at extreme angles of shot and long zeroing ranges.
Following are some calculations sighting at the horizontal, +60 degrees, and -60 degrees with the target at 100 M and the rifle zeroed at 100M.  Vo is 800 M/S.

X   100 M
θ   0.043867086 Degrees
Vo  800 M/S
Yo (Rifle Height)   1.5 M

Vox 799.9997655 M/S
Voy 0.6125  M/S
t   0.125000037 S
Y   -2.24398E-08    M
Yo plus Y   1.499999978 M
Target Height   1.5 M
Impact relative to target   -2.24398E-08    M   -8.83456E-07    Inch
R (Range)   99.99997069 M
α (Zero Angle Correction)   0.043867086 Degrees
Sighting Angle  0   Degrees

X   100 M
θ   60.04386709 Degrees
Vo  800 M/S
Yo (Rifle Height)   1.5 M

Vox 399.4694546 M/S
Voy 693.1263628 M/S
t   0.250332031 S
Y   173.2046663 M
Yo plus Y   174.7046663 M
Target Height   174.7050736 M
Impact relative to target   -0.000407288    M   -0.016034961    Inch
R (Range)   56506.69594 M
α (Zero Angle Correction)   0.043867086 Degrees
Sighting Angle  60  Degrees

X   100 M
θ   -59.95613291    Degrees 
Vo  800 M/S 
Yo (Rifle Height)   1.5 M

Vox 400.5303357 M/S 
Voy -692.5138628    M/S 
t   0.249668979 S
Y   -173.2046687    M
Yo plus Y   -171.7046687    M
Target Height   -171.7050736    M
Impact relative to target   0.000404954 M   0.015943081
R (Range)   -56606.69591    M
α (Zero Angle Correction)   0.043867086 Degrees 
Sighting Angle  -60 Degrees

This is my analysis of the situation. I would welcome any comments or certainly any corrections to my methodology.